# Using String Functions in ADFS Claims Rule Language

Tags: regex, adfs, claims

The business case is Active Directory Federation Server as Identity Provider passing a claim to Salesforce as Service Provider.

In ADFS, we map `sAMAccountName` to Name ID.

In Salesforce, we populate Federated ID on the user record with the value of `sAMAccountName`.

Works great, assuming case matches. Our AD `sAMAccountName` values are not consistently cased (new ones are, but over the years this has not been true). Rather than intervene at the AD level to make case consistent for records that predate our AD provisioning policy and process, I would prefer to transform the ADFS claim to force case (and populate Salesforce Federated ID with the same case).

I wondered if RegExReplace could work in an ADFS claim, but have not found any examples. Has anyone solved this or a similar problem? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the case transform via a custom attribute store.

It allows you total flexibility to do anything you want.

Refer: [String Processing Attribute Store Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh599320.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly with a helpful and informative link. It's a little mind-boggling to me that in order to implement a basic string operation in an ADFS issuance rule we need to maintain an entire Visual Studio project to register in GAC and ADFS a custom WIF class library. Am I understanding that right?

Comment: Not really - it's a custom attribute store which sits alongside ADFS - not an WIF extension. Then you use the custom attribute store as the source of the claim rather than AD.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I will give it a try. Perhaps some day Microsoft will enhance the claims language itself to incorporate such basic string operations.

Comment: @nzpcmad - by any chance do you have any github repos showing the implementation of a custom attribute store?